# Passing a text `prop` to an `option` element

Tags: reactjs, ecmascript-6, attributes, html-select

I'm trying to render a very generic `<option/>` tag, i want to pass it some props and just spread them as attributes.
`<option {...props}>{props.text}</option>`
As you can see, i'm using the `text` property of my object to set... well the `text` property of the element.
Consider this object passed in as `props`:
`{
  value: "someValue",
  text: "some text",
  "data-something": "something"
}`

With this object passed in, i will have the `value` and `data-something` set correctly, though `text` will set but will through a nice warning of:

> Unknown prop `text` on `<option>` tag...

I don't want to force the consumers to use the `label` attribute instead of the `text`.
Keep in mind that the consumer can pass any attributes to this option including `data-*`.
Is there a way to spread an object and excluding properties in an elegant way?
Or maybe there's a different way to set the `text` property of a DOM element?

```js
const cities = [
    {
        value: "nyc",
        text: "New York",
        'data-type': "city"
    },
    {
        value: "lnd",
        text: "London",
        'data-type': "city"
    },
    {
        value: "TLV",
        text: "Tel Aviv",
        'data-type': "city"
    }
]

const Option = (props) => {
    return (
        <option {...props}>{props.text}</option>
    )
}

class Selector extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props)
        this.state = {
            selectedObject: props.selectedObject || {
                value: "defualt",
                text: "Select...",
                'data-type': "default"
            }
        }
        this.onChange = this.onChange.bind(this);
    }

    onChange(e) {
        const { onChange } = this.props;
        const { selectedObject } = this.state;
        const selectedOption = e.target.selectedOptions[0];
        const nextSelectedObject = {
            value: selectedOption.value,
            text: selectedOption.text,
            'data-type': selectedOption.dataset.type
        };
        const nextState = Object.assign({}, ...selectedObject, ...nextSelectedObject);
        this.setState({
            selectedObject: nextState
        }, onChange && onChange(nextSelectedObject));
    }

    render() {
        const { selectedObject } = this.state;
        const { options } = this.props;
        return (
            <div>
                <select name="" id="" value={selectedObject.value} onChange={this.onChange}>
                    {options.map((o,i) => <Option key={i} {...o} />)}
                </select>
            </div>
        )
    }
}

ReactDOM.render(<Selector options={cities} />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you want to do is pull the text out of the property to pass to the object

```
const Option = (props) => {
    const toExtendProps = Object.assign({}, props);
    delete toExtendProps.text; 
    return (
        <option {...toExtendProps }>{props.text}</option>
    )
}
```